# Bundles request returning Cache-Control response header as no-cahe when deployed on Azure Web APP

Tags: bundling-and-minification, cache-control, azure-web-app-service, azure-cdn

We are using CDN for bundling in Azure Web APP. We have implemented  approach given in below article.But it seems that for every bundle request to CDN, CDN is only forwarding this request to Azure Web-App,instead of delivering it from its own cache making it more time consuming

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-websites-with-cdn/#integrate-aspnet-bundling-and-minification-with-azure-cdn

On debugging, found that Cache-Control value is set to no-Cache from azure-web-app. In Bundle Request URL we are using build number for Querystring value.

URL looks like - ~/bundles/lib?v=26948

Caveat is ,this works well when deployed on local.Somehow azure web app is sending wrong value for Cache-Control

Below is fiddler trace for bundle request on webapp.

```
GET /bundles/lib?v=26948 HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Host: mseventsdevtertiary.azurewebsites.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Language: en-IN,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, peerdist
X-P2P-PeerDist: Version=1.1
X-P2P-PeerDistEx: MinContentInformation=1.0, MaxContentInformation=2.0


HTTP/1.1 200 OK              
Cache-Control: no-cache   
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: -1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Mon, 27 Jun 2016 09:02:28 GMT
```